# Activate Screen Mirroring through android application

Tags: java, android, samsung-smart-tv, samsung-mobile-sdk

I am creating a react native application able to activate the screen mirroring of the devices when clicking on a button.

The phone is connected to the same network than the TV, and we suppose that the TV is in the "Screen Mirroring" source.

All the TVs are Samsung, and the android too, if it's relevant.

I First tested with the Allshare Framework SDK, but it doesnt seem that Allshare is used on new devices, because It's not installed and I can't install it.

There is a new SDK for samsung called Smart View, but there is nothing in the documentation relevant to the screen mirroring issue.

I'm really stuck on this because I don't find any information about the any useful sdk for screen mirroring.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Any luck with your search?

Comment: have you found anything yet ?